# preventing resized images from becoming blurred

Tags: imagemagick

im trying to resize image from 72x72 to 512x512 with following command

```
convert input.png -resize 512x512 output.png
```

but the output image (output.png) become blur

how to prevent resized images from becoming blurred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to prevent resized images from becoming blurred

If you want a pixelated image of the original use [`-sample`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sample)

```
# Create small image.
convert -size 72x72 plasma: 72x72.png
```

[image: 72x72.png]

```
# Magnify the image with pixel subsampling.
convert 72x72.png -sample 512 512x512_sample.png
```

[image: 512x512_sample.png]

It's true that you can't restore missing data when upscaling images, but there's a lot of various algorithms to calculate what *may* be missing.

Try using the [`-filter`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#filter) option in addition to `-resize`, and checkout the wonderful usage examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best you can do is use a sharper -filter such as catrom and then do post processing using -unsharp.

```
convert input.png -filter catrom -resize 512x512 -unsharp 0xSigma output.png
```

where sigma is the sharpening value, try sigma=1 or 2 (or as desired)

But it will not maintain the same quality as the input as others have mentioned above.

See -unsharp at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#unsharp

Comment: You might also see or try the suggestions at https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. For an equal sharpness, you would need more data in the bigger image. Since you have only the data from a small image the result is blurred.

Look at it the other way, if what you asked was possible, instead of compressing the 512x512 image, we would first scale it down to 72x72, compress that (much smaller file) and sent it over with instructions to scale it up to 512x512.